# Android: Open PPT from my app

Tags: android

I want to open a .ppt file in my app. I've installed Documents To Go app.
But, alert dialog displays "No application can perform this action".

I've also tried ACTON_SEND but same message. Please help me.

```
filename = "/sdcard/test.ppt";
    File file = new File(filename);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.i(TAG, "aa file "+URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename));
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, path);
    intent.setType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with.."));
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the question. But: What is that title supposed to tell me? I don't get it. :D

Comment: @alextsc I've also a question about BigBlueButton, i wrote the question but didn't post because there is no tag with that. So, the question is saved as draft and i didn'e see the title. can i change it now?

Comment: Changed.. Please, can you give the answer if you know.

Comment: Thanks. No sorry, never did that myself. Not even installed Documents to go ever, so no idea what's wrong. Edit: Though I have some general idea/advice: Don't hardcode the path to the sdcard. It might change across devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead to get the path, it works on all devices. And are you sure this hardcoded path is correct?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice, I changed that now. And I'm also able to open the .ppt file. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent.setDataAndType()` to set the Uri and the mime-type at the same time; just calling `setType()` clears out the Uri that you set in the constructor.